# how to change the background of each item in a listview in Windows 8 using C # and xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, background, windows-8

I'm trying to create a listview in Windows 8 using C # and xaml. I want want each list item to have 
a different background.

Is it possible to be done using C# and XAML?

How can I set the background of each item by c# XAML code?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12010234/901059).  You can use the row index with a data converter to set the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a property of a custom object (or a property of whatever object the list is already binding to). If that property never notifies of changes, then those backgrounds will stay whatever you set them. If you want them to be based on some value, the custom object should be given the means to determine how/what the color is to be based on.

Answer (score 0):

Here You go as simple as this.

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,1122,0">
    <ListView>
            <ListViewItem Background="blue">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello"></TextBlock></ListViewItem>

            <ListViewItem Background="green">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello"></TextBlock>
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

Tested using visual studio 2012. c# XAML