# Update ListViewItem Controls in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I have a ListView using a custom ListView in my WinRT application. The custom ListView class simply overrides PrepareContainerForItemOverride() so that I can have alternating backgrounds, as per this Microsoft suggestion:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750769%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

As is stated there, when items are removed from the list, it doesn't automatically update the alternate backgrounds. It provides a solution for this:

```
ICollectionView dataView =
  CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(theListView.ItemsSource);
dataView.Refresh();
```

However, CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView is in System.Windows.Data - which is not available to WinRT.

I've tried searching the documentation and the web for an alternative but I just keep stumbling onto WPF code. I can't find any way to refresh the data - at the moment all I can come up with is removing all the data and re-adding it, which is obviously mad.

Comment: This question might be able to help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010099/metro-app-listview-how-to-alternate-background-colour-of-listviewitems][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010099/metro-app-listview-how-to-alternate-background-colour-of-listviewitems

Comment: I managed to get that to go as far as I currently have - i.e. works perfectly when items are added as long as none are removed, but there's no recalculation on removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a simple "solution" so I thought I'd include it here.

I just added the following to App.xaml.cs:

In OnLaunched, at the end, after:

```
Window.Current.Activate();
```

I added

```
Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += ForceListUpdate;
```

ForceListUpdate being:

```
private void ForceListUpdate(object sender, ICoreWindowEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Window.Current.Visible)
    {
        DataSource.ForceListUpdate();
    }
}
```

and DataSource.ForceListUpdate being:

```
public static void ForceListUpdate()
{
    if (_dataSource.Content.Count != 0)
        _dataSource.Content.Move(0, 0);
}
```

I had done various things with disabling animations while deleting, but that was pretty ugly. With this method, if an item is removed, then the alternating colours are mismatched - until the window isn't visible, at which point it refreshes. It's by far the nicest solution I've found.