# How do I alternate a ListViewItem's background color?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am developing windows store app.

I need to show the ListViewItems with alternate background colors, without using any library.

The ListView is bound and loading dynamically.

I tried doing it by getting the item index and then setting the background color accordingly.
It worked perfectly, but I noticed that it works for only those items which are in the current view. When I scroll down, there is no background color for the other items.

I mean it does not work for items which are not in the view.

Pls suggest any other approach.

Comment: could you please show your existing xaml code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Metro app - ListView - how to alternate background colour of ListViewItems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010099/metro-app-listview-how-to-alternate-background-colour-of-listviewitems)

Answer (score -4):

wrap the `Item` inside of a div and give it a class. In your CSS alternate the `background-color` like this:

```
<div class="listview">
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.listview {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.item:nth-child(odd) {
    display:block;
    background:pink;
}
```

You can also use the [AlternatingItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.alternatingitemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to set a background color if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: right, so just wrap a `div` like the `item` class in my answer around your `<ItemTemplate>`. Does that not work? Or setting the background color of an `AlternatingItemTemplate`?

Comment: Although the question doesn't mention it, I suspect OP is using WPF; and therefore not able to use HTML/CSS based solutions. Just an educated guess, though.

Comment: @Flater Looking back at the question I agree. The ListView still has an `AlternatingItemTemplate` I thought. Though, I could be wrong.

Comment: The question is tagged c# & xaml so why is this a html/css answer?